# Counting decimal numbers in Java

Tags: java, while-loop, integer, double, java.util.scanner

I have an issue where i am trying to count the amount of numbers with a decimal point however it is just counting whenever there is an integer even if it is a whole one.

```
    Scanner cd = new Scanner(name); // count double
    Scanner cn = new Scanner(name).useDelimiter("[^0-9]+");  // count int

            while(cn.hasNextInt()) {
            cn.nextInt();
            numberOfInts++;

        }    

        while(cd.hasNextDouble()) {
            cd.nextDouble();
            numberOfDecimals++;
        }
```

so yeah the number of decimals justs counts whenever a integer is scanned, even if it is a whole number, i want it too just count numbers with a decimal point.

Comment: Can there be a maximum of one number (of any type) per line, or could there be multiple numbers on a single line?

Comment: Multiple its safe to assume that the contents of the file is unkown

Comment: Without a known format and clear delimiters, how do you know whether `12345` is a single integer, or a list of five single-digit integers? Similarly, how can you be sure that `12.34` is a decimal and not a period-delimited pair of integers?

Comment: Well for the purpose of the question lets assume that 12.7 indeeds means that it is a double and 123 means one hundred and twenty three.

Comment: But what goes around those numbers to mark their beginning and end? Spaces? Quotes? Newlines? It sounds like you're going to be forced to use guesswork, and that usually means trouble in the long run.

Comment: Newlines and spaces is all i know for sure thats all i can work with and have worked with up to this point